# Defining common message across wsdls

Tags: wsdl

I'm writing three different web services in three wsdls. The services all share a common type of generic error message. The three services are defined in three different namespaces but I want the error message to be defined in a fourth namespace. Is there a way to "import" or "include" the message-type into the three wsdl-files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that should be possible. Use the `<import>` element to import the shared WSDL, in the portType's operation, you can fully qualify the name of message, i.e. you need to bind the fourth namespace to a prefix (e.g. ns4) and then add a reference like this:

```
<portType name="MyPortType">
    <operation name="MyOperation">
       <input message="tns:myInput"/>
       <output message="tns:myOutput"/>
       <fault message="ns4:myFault"/>
    </operation>
</portType>
```

See http://www.w3.org/TR/wsdl#_style for further reference about the import mechanism.